# Как настроить форматирование инициализации массивов в Эклипсе?

Tags: eclipse, java

Здравствуйте, уважаемые.

Бьюсь с настройками форматтера, пытаюсь сделать читаемые инициализаторы массивов, но самое лучшее, что получилось, это:

```
    public static int[][] INT_2_ARRAY = {
        {
                1, 2, 3
        }, {
                10, 20, 30
        }, {
                1234, 2435, 567, 8679, 78678
        },
};
```

А хотелось бы в таком виде:

```
    public static int[][] INT_2_ARRAY = {
        {1, 2, 3},
        {10, 20, 30},
        {1234, 2435, 567, 8679, 78678},
};
```

Таким образом, нужно разделять новой линией только первый уровень массива.
Возможно ли это?

Если не возможно - поделитесь наиболее читабельными настройками инициализаторов массивов.